# Grouping Array in Object with respect to created_at timestamp

Tags: php, laravel

I have JSON data which returns a users comment:

```
[
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "delectus aut autem",
    "completed": false,
    "created_at": "10/09/2018"
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 2,
    "title": "quis ut nam facilis et officia qui",
    "completed": false,
    "created_at": "10/09/2018"
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 3,
    "title": "fugiat veniam minus",
    "completed": false,
    "created_at": "15/09/2018"
  }]
```

I would like to group this data by the **created_at** property in the object with the array. I want the data to look like where an object with the data array and there the same objects date **created_at**:

```
[
  {
    created_at: '10/09/2018',
    data: [
      {
        userId: 1,
        id: 1,
        title: 'delectus aut autem',
        completed: false,
        created_at: '10/09/2018'
      },
      {
        userId: 1,
        id: 2,
        title: 'quis ut nam facilis et officia qui',
        completed: false,
        created_at: '10/09/2018'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    created_at: '15/09/2018',
    data: [
      {
        userId: 1,
        id: 3,
        title: 'fugiat veniam minus',
        completed: false,
        created_at: '15/09/2018'
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

My code is group by a column name in the array, but not object with data array. Any idea?

```
$result = [];

foreach ($data as $item) {
    $column = $item[$by_column];
    unset($item[$by_column]);
    if (isset($result[$column])) {
        $result[$column][] = $item;
    } else {
        $result[$column] = array($item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well. The above array is a json string or a php array? Your for loop treat them as a php array but it is a json string. The answer will differ based on the what it is. Could you clarify

Comment: Rinsad Ahmed, i copy this json from my frontend and laravel will answer string json for frontend.

Comment: so you are posting a json string from the front end right?

Comment: Rinsad Ahmed, yes!

Answer (score 0):

Here if the array which you have. and you can achieve your requirement by using laravel `collect` helper function.

```
$arr = [
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "delectus aut autem",
    "completed": false,
    "created_at": "10/09/2018"
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 2,
    "title": "quis ut nam facilis et officia qui",
    "completed": false,
    "created_at": "10/09/2018"
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 3,
    "title": "fugiat veniam minus",
    "completed": false,
    "created_at": "15/09/2018"
  }
];

$jsonObj = collect($arr);
$groupedArray = $jsonObj->groupBy("created_at");

dd($groupedArray->toArray());
```

In above example you can convert array to collection and then can use collection group by helper function then you will get output like this

```
array(
  "10/09/2018" => [
    {
      "userId": 1,
      "id": 1,
      "title": "delectus aut autem",
      "completed": false,
      "created_at": "10/09/2018"
    },
    {
      "userId": 1,
      "id": 2,
      "title": "quis ut nam facilis et officia qui",
      "completed": false,
      "created_at": "10/09/2018"
    }
  ],
  "15/09/2018" => [
    {
      "userId": 1,
      "id": 3,
      "title": "fugiat veniam minus",
      "completed": false,
      "created_at": "15/09/2018"
    }
  ]
)
```

I think this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use collection grouping method of laravel

```
$data->groupBy();
```